# Designing a quick-lookup address database

Tags: mysql

If I were to design a database in MySQL to the following specifications:

1) Over 25mil records

2) Columns of house number, street, town, city, postcode

3) street, town, city and postcode need to be fulltext-searchable (on the front-end side, the search will be running on AJAX off a text-input field with immediate drop-down results)

How would I design the above?

I was thinking with working with a single table - is this a bad idea? Am not sure whether to normalize across different tables, given this is address data. I am also thinking that if working with a single table, I would do a FULLTEXT index across the searchable fields.

I have not worked with such a large DB before. Is the above a bad idea?

---

UPDATE #1:

Decided to normalize the street and postcode columns, which are the only ones actually being searched on (re-checked the original specification). Did some quick math and cardinality of street name is 2% and postcodes 6% of total data set, so I think this is the best way forward.

Currently running the import of 29 million rows - will take about 5 hours. Will update again later on performance tests for the sake of wrapping up this question.

Answer (score 0):

Your design sounds reasonable.  But.  Are you sure that the addresses in the database all conform to the " , , " format?  What about "c/o" addresses ("care/of")?  Unit/apartment/floor/suite numbers?  What about specific building names ("Barack Obama, White House, Washington, DC")?

In the United States, there are various exceptions to this address layout.  For example, there is something called "Rural Routes", whose format is "RR  BOX " (described [here](http://pe.usps.com/text/pub28/28c2_021.htm)).  There are PO Boxes and military addresses.  In fact, I just learned that the US Post Office has a publication describing all sorts of different address formats ([here](http://pe.usps.com/text/pub28/)).

A more general form is something like "Address Line 1", "Address Line 2", "City", "Post Code".  There are services that standardize addresses for much of the world, and even software available for this purpose.

Your idea of using full text search is a good idea.  When looking for a partial match on a street name, for instance, it will be much faster.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. If you think it's worth a shot then I will give it a go. I am not so bothered about the quirky addresses - my primary concern is the speed of lookup, as it needs to happen in near-realtime (in response to characters being typed in an input field). I did not want to spend the time importing the data and building the indexes without some indication of whether performance would be sufficient in a single-table and FULLTEXT design.

Comment: @RC . . . Let me say.  It is reasonable and worth trying.  *However* for real time responses on 25 million addresses, you might need more custom code.  Google, for instance, does some rather sophisticated stuff to support its real-tem query recommendations.